# Don't sanitize the more link in a view?

Tags: views

Currently any HTML added to the "More link" output in a view is sanitized.  This is undesirable for me.  How can this be changed so that this field is not sanitized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way would probably be to do something along the lines of...

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {

  $name=$vars['name'];
  $display_id=$vars['display_id'];

  if ($name=='THE_VIEW_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR' && $display=='THE_DISPLAY_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR') {

     $vars['more']= // the exact html you want to have in your more link

  }

}
```

If you would rather work with just templates, you can copy `views-view.tpl.php` to your theme and name it appropriately, eg, `views-view--VIEW_NAME.tpl.php`, and then modify the following in it:

```
<?php if ($more): ?>
  <?php print $more; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to whatever you want `$more` to be.

Clear theme registry/caches and you should be all set in both cases.

ADDITION DUE TO COMMENTARY:

Gotcha.  However, the more link is generated from inside the view display plugin via `render_more_link()` and it eventually creates it by calling up a theme template via...

```
return theme($theme, $path, check_plain($this->use_more_text())); // D6
```

or

```
return theme($theme, array('more_url' => $path, 'link_text' => check_plain($this->use_more_text()), 'view' => $this->view)); // D7
```

...both implementations of which `check_plain()` the text entered via the UI.

So, in order for this to work via the UI, you will most probably need to craft up a new views display plugin without that `check_plain()` in there.

It also goes without saying that you will need to have implicit trust in the folks working with the UI to not enter any errant HTML in there.

Comment: This works if all you want to do is enter the data programatically.  However, folk need to be able to enter data through Views UI.

Comment: gotcha, I added in some more information.

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution for more links with exposed filters in the url.

```
function mvo_blocks_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  if($vars['more'] != NULL) {
    $display = $vars['view']->display_handler;
    if(!$path = $display->get_option('link_url')){
      $path = $display->get_path();
    }
    $vars['more'] = theme('views_more', array('more_url' => $path, 'link_text' => check_plain($display->use_more_text()), 'view' => $display->view));
  }
}
```